# JFileChooser Browse Dialogue From JSP

Tags: java, client-side, jfilechooser

I have two jsp files. From one jsp, I am calling another for JFileChooser browse dialog.

But when I load the url from a client machine the browse dialog open in server machine.
I searched it over the net. But I cannot found a solution. Please post a solution.

Answer (score 2):

JSP and Java Swing are completely different UI technologies. JSP lets you create web-based UIs, Swing lets you create desktop client UIs.

You can simply use an HTML form with an input of type="file" to create a file-chooser dialog for your web-clients. See:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html

The reason the JFileChooser opened up on the server is because that's where Java is running. Swing isn't aware that the program is actually a Servlet-container and that your users are web-clients.

Comment: I need directory browser. not file browser. that is why I did like this. html does not provide directory browsing facility